# Grub menu screen flicker

Tags: grub2, screen, flicker

I am having a strange problem on my Dell Inspiron 1505 laptop. When starting the computer the grub screen flickers or every few seconds. I don't know if it would be called a flicker. The screen actually superimposes another menu over the existing menu.

It starts on the right side of the screen and then moves to where it normally sits. This "flicker" refreshes every few seconds and looks very unprofessional when starting up around other users.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

i also have the same problem over the past 2 weeks, installing burg in the  place of grub2 will help you out, here is a [link about burg along with install and use instructions](http://www.overclock.net/t/1251224/guide-installing-burg-and-super-boot-manager-in-ubuntu-inc-12-04-lts)